# Dealing with outliers when Inter Quartile Range is 0

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, outliers, data-preprocessing

I am working with `Classification` Machine Learning problems and have come across a problem where I have 0 IQR for my data. No matter what technique I use, `square root`, `cube root` , `log` transform I still get the same IQR (obviously it is used to scale the data uniformly).

How do I get rid of outliers in my data. Below is the Value Counts for the data.

```
Amount  Number of People
360.0    843
180.0     66
480.0     23
300.0     20
240.0      8
84.0       7
120.0      4
36.0       3
60.0       3
12.0       2
350.0      1
6.0        1
```

In this data, `Q1`=`Q3`= 360 making `IQR`=0

Comment: No one to one transformation can separate equal values. If 843 values (86%) are together at 360, they will stay together at whatever you transform 360 to.

Comment: So how would I deal with outliers then? @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica

Comment: If you want to base your definition of being an outlier on the IQR, such as median $\pm 1.5*IQR$, then you have your answer: everything but 360 is an outlier.

Comment: so what do I do then, @Dave? delete all those entries?

Comment: What are you doing with your data set once you examine it for outliers?

Comment: Without a specific model and purpose, what  would make something an outlier, and why would you need to identify them? It sounds like you don't have a useful definition of "outlier"

Comment: @Dave building a classification machine learning model.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica I'm working on Classification models. I can not drop rows as I have mixed the training and test data for pre processing and I just have few hundreds entries. What should be an approach for this outlier correction?

Comment: And why do you want to eliminate data points? “Outliers” can be quite telling. (Really, I call an outlier a mistake, like an intern entering $6.0\times 10^{9}m$ instead of $6.0\times 10^{-9}m$ when you know you’re working at a  nanometer scale. I prefer to use “extreme value” to describe a real observation that is outside the norm.)

Comment: @Dave - so you man to say I just keep the data as it is? no transform? nothing? just the simple min-max transformation?

Comment: Quite possibly. If a few points would have a dramatic impact on results it suggests changing the model/loss function, rather than the data

Comment: At the least its not yet clear that omitting points on the basis of such an arbitrary criterion is a good strategy.

Comment: @Glen_b you might remember who posted this over the summer, but someone else was asking about how to handle outliers, seemingly following a paper by a Nobel winner, and one of the senior members had a comment like “if he’s doing that, then revoke his Nobel Prize.” The method was along the lines of removing points that wind up being inconvenient.

Comment: ... whose summer?

Comment: Stamp out hemispherism on CV!

Comment: @Dave I did locate a relevant post from July (since I supposed you meant the northern hemisphere's summer) which was discussing the above sort of error and the economics prize (not actually a Nobel but let's leave that aside), but the comments don't presently seem to mention revoking a prize so I don't know if it's the same one you were referring to.

Comment: Maybe it wasn’t as extreme as revoking the prize, but I think you found the one I meant. Could you please link it?